# GO in IntelliJ IDEA. Multiple File and Error Undefined: Data

Tags: intellij-idea, go

**I want use IntelliJ IDE Community Edition** to write code in **GO (GoLang)**. I instaled right plugin, and instaled all need tools to build application. 
My application consists with two below file. Each is in direcytory *../EventServer*.

- Main.go
- Data.go

If I want to run project from IntelliJ using function Run (Ctlr+Shift+F10) and I **get below error**

```
/usr/lib/go/bin/go build -o "/tmp/Build Main.go and run0go" -gcflags "-N -l" /my/home/blah/EventServer/Main.go
# command-line-arguments
./Main.go:11: undefined: Data
```

I can without any problem compiled code from terminal come in to direcytory with project and execution command

```
:~/Pulpit/EventServer$ go build
./EventServer 
Hello
dane w strukturze someone
```

tree direcytory and files looks like

```
EventServer$ tree -a
.
├── Data.go
├── EventServer
├── EventServer.iml
├── .idea
│   ├── compiler.xml
│   ├── copyright
│   │   └── profiles_settings.xml
│   ├── libraries
│   │   └── GOPATH__EventServer_.xml
│   ├── misc.xml
│   ├── modules.xml
│   ├── .name
│   ├── vcs.xml
│   └── workspace.xml
└── Main.go
```

I suppose that command to run is bad, because compiler trying build program with only one file Main.go but not with all files. Right command should be

```
$ go run *.go
```

But I do not know where Can I set this.

I also set GOPATH to:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/Pulpit/EventServer
```

This also hasn't help

**CODE**

**Main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Hello")
    abcd := Data{"someone" , "1234567"}
    fmt.Printf("dane w strukturze %s ", abcd.Name)

}
```

And  **Data.go**

```
package main


type Data struct {
Name string
Phone string

}
```

**SYSTEM: LINUX**

Answer (score 31):

**----------------------SOLVED-------------------------------------------SOLVED---------------------**

Steps

- Project must be found in directory `for/example/MyProject/src/HERE_DIRECTORY_WITH_YOUR_SOURCE_GO_FILE`
  sub direcytory **src** is important
- Go to `Run --> Edit Configurations`
- Find below position

[image]

- Change `Run Kind` to `Package`
- In Position `Package` write Your folder with Your code (Shold be Highlight it is correct)
- Click On PLUS icon in left top corner, and Add `Go Application`
- Apply changes
- In the right top corner main window IDE You see small icon Play

[image]

- Chose early defined `Go Application` my is Unamed
- Click Play
- An Joy :D

Comment: Thanks for that!

have been able to use the debugger?

Comment: Yes ofcorse. I use debugger very often. If I good remember I nothing to do with setup for him, just works, but debugger for `go`  for me is little meager, but works, may be in future something will change. If I help You please give me vote up :)

Comment: For me this says package not found in your case RightApp package is not found

Comment: you made my day.

Comment: Boom. Fixed for me in both Intellij + Gogland

Comment: I Think You Should Not Edit Defaults (As Shown In Screenshot), As It Could Be Of Use Another Time, In Another Project.

Answer (score 6):

Let say you are having a project with src/ sub directory and two .go files inside: hello.go and typetest.go and both defines the same package "main". One of them (hello.go) also implements func main().

To make it compile as whole you need to make sure two things are configured properly: GOPATH and Run/Debug configuration.

Open the Project Libraries/GOPATH settings:

For **Gogland**

File -> Settings -> Go

For **Intellij IDEA**

File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Go -> Go Libraries

Makes sure the GOPATH for the project looks something like that:

[GOPATH settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKRYe.jpg)

Next, open Run -> Edit Configurations and make sure your configuration looks similar to this:

[Run/Debug configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JH2W.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can add second file (in your case Data.go) as Go tool arguments field in Run/Debug Configurations. I read about this here: https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/2013 near the end of discussion. Example below (I used 2 files HelGo.go and aaa.go) worked for me:

[Go Run Configuration with 2 files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vabS1.png)

Intellij objected in these 2 files were in different folders, and so both of them has to be same package (main).
On the other side I couldn't make any advises on this page work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem with a complete list of checking. Usually, there are multiple problems combined with each other.

First of all, check your GOPATH settings, there are two ways:

1. use the command line to check your go environment:

   ```
   $ go env
   ```

   you will get a global environment setting, make sure your GO folders are correct. If you are using some local packages, be aware of them too.
2. check your Build tool setting, whether you have added all your resources files into your dependencies. This is another way to set up your project GOPATH, and do not affects the global settings.

Secondly, check your Run/Debug configuration, and make sure your settings have located the **main package** or **main file**.  No matter which kind of configuration you use, this is always the start.

Answer (score -1):

Sarp Kaya, just follow Mbded steps. Additional step is, ensure that your **additional** GOPATH should be there.

For example, this is our `~/.profile GOPATH`

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/lib/Go:$HOME/Development/Go
```

The first path used by go get processes etc, while your active go development directory goes to the next path.

According to our config, the RightApp exact path should be `$HOME/Development/Go/src/RightApp`.