# How to add new file to Go project

Tags: intellij-idea, go

I am using the Go plugin for IntelliJ Idea.

I'm not sure how I got my project working like this but I am able to run my Main.go file and it includes all my other files in the project that I can reference. That is perfect.

The problem now is that when I go and create a new "*.go" file it's not included in the IDE build and I get compiled errors wherever I refer to the contents of that file.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you correctly use `go build` in the project directory using the command-line ?

Comment: Yea, that's what i've fallen back to. I just run from terminal right now. Annoying though.

Comment: If I good understood You (probably)... Do You try in Intellij run Your project as package ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508254/go-in-intellij-idea-multiple-file-and-error-undefined-data/32509574#32509574   I also have this same problem when I started with this IDE

Comment: Hmm, thanks. That's strange it works. I wonder why it worked before?

Comment: Post as the answer.. I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set GOPATH in the ~/.bash_profile, e.g.

```bash
GOPATH=~/code/go
export GOPATH
```

and `source ~/.bash_profile` or restart the terminal. it will go into effect;

then put *.go or go project related with the main.go under the GOPATH.

finally, main.go will find the *.go.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of run configurations for Go applications:
- Go Single file -> which is the equivalent of go run file.go
- Go Application -> which is the equivalent of go build file / package and run the binary

By the sound of it, you want to run a Go Application with Run kind set to package. There you'll need to type the full package name, for example: github.com/dlsniper/demo/cmd/democmd 
At the moment support for running multiple files / building a directory is not present (there are some issues opened for it)